# Codeigniter Call to a member function set_userdata() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter, php4

I am getting a fatal error in a CI app that I just moved from a php4 shared host to a php5 shared host.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function set_userdata() on a non-object in /home/chuck_ravenna/bob.ravennainteractive.com/system/application/helpers/authenticate_helper.php on line 13
```

*Code in full located in the link below*

https://gist.github.com/1474173

I am trying to figure out if the php version could be the issue.  The site runs fine on the old server, and the new server doesn't have php4 as an option.

The specific code line thats breaking is:

```
    $this->session->set_userdata("admin", $user[0]["admin"]);
```

Comment: Why are you calling `session_start()` and using `$_SESSION["user"]`, rather than just using the CI Session library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `$this` inside a helper as a helper file is just a collection of functions (no class there). To use the functionality provided by `$this` of controller, you'll have to do:

```
$ci = & get_instance();
$ci->session->set_userdata("admin", $user[0]["admin"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

$CI =& get_instance();

$CI->load->library('session');

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the session librairy in the constructor and after the parent::__construct() instruction?

Answer (score -2):

You are using the default configuration of Codeigniter.
The problem is: NO DATABASE CONFIGURATION DONE!
You must enter here: \YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME\application\config\database.php

and you must open this file with a text editor.

Set the following variables and you are done:

```
$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = "127.0.0.1";
$db['default']['username'] = "root";
$db['default']['password'] = "";
$db['default']['database'] = "NameOfYourDatabase";
```